# How to pass in a target file in sslscan.exe

Tags: ssl

I am trying to pass in a list of hosts to perform an sslscan on using `--targets=<file>` option.

What is the correct way to do this? I have tried using the absolute path to the file and stored the file in the same folder as the sslscan.exe.

The documentation is very skinny and doesnt provide an example of how to use the  `[option]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--targets="hosts.txt"`  did in fact work on a second machine. It was placed into the same directory as the `sslscan.exe` file